# Games with two knight promotions in them

Tags: knights, pawn-promotion, famous-games

Games with two knight promotions are extremely rare, but a few have existed. In an [article](https://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/chess2/cql.htm) of his, Tim Krabbe stated that, about the game [Zurakhov - Koblentz](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1156733), "This is one in only 5 games with two serious Knight-promotions. 57.g8N is the only winning move, and also a rare non-checking Knight-promotion. 79.c8N is not the only winning move, but in human terms: the best move."

He states that there are 5 double knight promotion games, but I have only ever found four on chessgames.com. Here is my list, in order of date.

[MacDonnell-Bird, 1874](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1075750)

[Zurakhov-Koblent, 1956](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1156733)

[Schweber - Wexler, 1964](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1747606)

"This is the only game with two Knight promotions that were the strongest move. Promotions to Queen would have been equally strong, but as the Knight promotions were checks, they were more obvious, and therefore genuine." -[Tim Krabbe](https://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/records/records.htm)

[Kucuksari-Betanli, 2017](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1859385)

Can anyone find anymore games that feature two knight promotions?

Comment: I played several with more of them.  But I was toying with a guy who refused to resign and ended up mating him after a long game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not all the games are by strong players, let alone, players, who are well-known, but here is a complete list in the Mega 2019 database. If you would like to see a particular game, or two, I can post the PGN, and add it to this answer.

This one is interesting since one of players is famous, and both promotions happened so early in the game.

```
 [Event "Greenhills op"]
 [Site "Greenhills"]
 [Date "1989.??.??"]
 [Round "?"]
 [White "Valdez, P."]
 [Black "Xu, Jun"]
 [Result "0-1"]
 [ECO "A25"]
 [BlackElo "2510"]
 [PlyCount "44"]
 [EventDate "1989.07.??"]
 [EventType "swiss"]
 [EventRounds "12"]
 [EventCountry "PHI"]
 [SourceTitle "EXT 2010"]
 [Source "ChessBase"]
 [SourceDate "2010.11.25"]
 [SourceVersion "1"]
 [SourceVersionDate "2010.11.25"]
 [SourceQuality "1"]
 [FEN ""]

 1. c4 e5 2. Nc3 Nc6 3. g3 g6 4. Bg2 Bg7 5. d3 d6 6. Rb1 f5 7. Bd2 Nf6 8. b4 O-O 9. b5 Ne7 10. Nf3 h6 11. O-O Be6 12. Qc1 Kh7 13. h3 Qc8 14. Kh2 Bf7 15. c5 g5 16. Qa3 g4 17. cxd6 gxf3 18. dxe7 fxg2 19. exf8=N+ Bxf8 20. Qa4 gxf1=N+ 21. Rxf1 Qd8 22. Qh4 Nd5 0-1
```

[image]

---

Here is a list of links to all of the games, minus the ones already in the question, from the list in order of date. Most of them are either the 365chess or chess-db databases. N/A is used for games that have not been found.

[Kiili-Katajainen,1990](https://www.365chess.com/game.php?gid=2081734)

[Valdez-Xu, 1989](https://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1149879)

[Natri-Salokangas, 1990](https://www.365chess.com/game.php?gid=20818750)

[Kosonen-Vuori, 1990](https://www.365chess.com/game.php?gid=2085357)

[Dobos-Lehtivaar, 1990](https://www.365chess.com/game.php?gid=2085612)

[Korhonen-Eskola, 1991](https://www.365chess.com/game.php?gid=2009990)

[Lehto-Ketola, 1991](https://www.365chess.com/game.php?gid=2010072)

[Carpenter-Scott, 1994](https://www.365chess.com/game.php?gid=1636919)

[Myc-Walach, 1994](https://www.365chess.com/game.php?gid=1666986)

[Sintici-Zubavicius, 1995](https://www.365chess.com/game.php?gid=1502262)

[Norqvist-Kochetkov, 1995](https://www.365chess.com/game.php?gid=1537864)

[Richards-Fongers, 1997](https://www.365chess.com/game.php?gid=1122597)

Rasmussen-Arnkilde, 1997-N/A

[Doettling-Euler, 1999](https://www.365chess.com/game.php?gid=784065)

[Quintero-Bognar, 1999](https://www.365chess.com/game.php?gid=857636)

[Mellem=Borchgrevink, 2000](https://www.365chess.com/game.php?gid=568600)

[Reich-Lauer, 2002](https://www.365chess.com/game.php?gid=243184)

[Choma-Karstens, 2004](https://www.365chess.com/game.php?gid=2895199)

[Urbisaglia-Del Cont Bernard, 2004](https://www.365chess.com/game.php?gid=3014243)

Vajcner-Vancat, 2006-N.A

Polok, Jagodzinski, 2006-N/A

[Moura-Goncalves, 2006](https://www.365chess.com/game.php?gid=3417098)

[Hager-Specht, 2007](https://www.365chess.com/game.php?gid=3524500)

KaunzingerSternheimer, 2008-N/A

Huszar-Gerendas, 2008-N/A

Kast-Becker, 2010-N/A

[Khamko-Prosvetov, 2010](https://chess-db.com/public/game.jsp?id=4199014.24123900.46865408.26682)

[Hapke-Uksini, 2010](https://chess-db.com/public/game.jsp?id=4655630.1628313.3949568.26695)

Bango-Bango, 2011-N/A

Simo-Volna, 2011-N/A

Woehl-Schwab, 2012-N/A

[Effenberger-Barak, 2013](https://chess-db.com/public/game.jsp?id=376370.387347.25627136.27940)

[Bellahcene-Barbot, 2014](https://www.365chess.com/game.php?gid=3910779)

[Lokwani-Lee, 2015](https://chess-db.com/public/game.jsp?id=448125.2026562.106763776.28857)

[Radenic-Fikus, 2015](https://chess-db.com/public/game.jsp?id=14536510.14544261.8321024.28866)

[Fridman-Svane, 2015](https://www.chessbomb.com/arena/2015-uka-german/03-Fridman_Daniel-Svane_Rasmus)

[Popchev-Dyulgerov, 2015](https://chess-db.com/public/game.jsp?id=2900165.2918978.137428736.28912)

[Davanso-Jenidarchiche, 2018](https://chess-db.com/public/game.jsp?id=22713042.2193310.46342656.29998)

Comment: P.S. In three of those games, there are actually 3, 4 and 5 promotions, but they are games where one side did not resign, and the other kept advancing all their pawns, and promoted everything. The promotions were not part of a grander strategy like the game I posted above.